# How do I run my CDK app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I created and built a new [CDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk) project:

```
mkdir myproj
cd myproj
cdk init --language typescript
npm run build
```

If I try to run the resulting javascript, I see the following:

```
PS C:\repos\myproj> node .\bin\myproj.js
CloudExecutable/1.0

Usage:
  C:\repos\myproj\bin\myproj.js REQUEST

REQUEST is a JSON-encoded request object.
```

What is the right way to run my app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to run your CDK programs directly, but rather use the [CDK Toolkit](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/tools.html) instead.

To synthesize an AWS CloudFormation from your app:

```
cdk synth --app "node .\bin\myproj.js"
```

To avoid re-typing the `--app` switch every time, you can setup a `cdk.json` file with:

```
{ "app": "node .\app\myproj.js" }
```

Note: A default `cdk.json` is created by `cdk init`, so you should already see it under `C:\repos\myproj`.

You can also use the toolkit to deploy your app into an AWS environment:

```
cdk deploy
```

Or list all the stacks in your app:

```
cdk ls
```

Answer (score 2):

The CDK application expects a request to be provided as a positional CLI argument when you're using the low-level API (aka running the app directly), for example:

```
node .\bin\myproj.js '{"type":"list"}'
```

It can also be passed as a Base64-encoded blob instead (that can make quoting the JSON less painful in a number of cases) - the Base64 needs to be prefixed with `base64:` in this case.

```
node .\bin\myproj.js base64:eyAidHlwZSI6ICJsaXN0IiB9Cg==
```

In order to determine what are the APIs that are available, and what arguments they expect, you can refer to the [`@aws-cdk/cx-api`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/cx-api/lib/cxapi.ts) specification.